# Check whether label is exist or not

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add `checkbox` dynamically by entering the label name.
Here I can add checkbox, but problem is if same label(case sensitive) is already present it should not allow user to add. Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="add"  onClick="add()" />
<ul id="container" style="list-style-type:none;">
</ul>
```

**Script**

```
var i=0;
function add() {
    var label = prompt("Please enter label name", "");
    if (label != null || label != "") {
        i++;  
        var title = label;
        var node = document.createElement('li');        
        node.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="check' + i + '" name="check' + i + '"><label for="check' + i + '">'+ title +'</label>';       
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

**[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abbse16h/)**

Comment: `querySelectorAll` and `for-loop` and `if` condition..

Comment: @Ray why did you delete your answer. That must be an another way for solving OP's issue.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, I was wondering if there are easier ways, why do i think otherwise.. ;(

Comment: @OP, If you want to do it by reading `DOM` => https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/abbse16h/4/

Comment: @RayonDabre your anwser is more suitable. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the labels in an array and check whether the new label is present in that array or not, then proceed inserting the new element.

```
var i = 0;
var labels = [];

function add() {
  var label = prompt("Please enter label name", "");
  if (label != null || label != "") {
    if (labels.indexOf(label) == -1) {
      labels.push(label); i++;
      var node = document.createElement('li');
      node.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="check' + i + '" name="check' + i + '"><label for="check' + i + '">' + labels[labels.length - 1] + '</label>';
      document.getElementById('container').appendChild(node);
    } else {
      alert("labels should be unique!")
    }
  }
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abbse16h/3/)

Comment: Thank you @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var i=0;
function add() {
    var label = prompt("Please enter label name", "");
    var exists = document.evaluate('//label[text()="' + label + '"]', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, exists).snapshotItem(0);

    if (exists) {
        return; 
    }

    if (label != null || label != "") {
        i++;  
        var title = label;
        var node = document.createElement('li');        
        node.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="check' + i + '" name="check' + i + '"><label for="check' + i + '">'+ title +'</label>';       
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data` attribute and `querySelector` to check for the existance.

```
var i=0;
function add() {
    var label = prompt("Please enter label name", "");
    var labels = ;
    if ((label != null || label != "") && !document.querySelector('label[data-value="'+label+'"]')) {
        i++;  
        var title = label;
        var node = document.createElement('li');        
        node.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="check' + i + '" name="check' + i + '"><label for="check' + i + '" data-value="'+title+'">'+ title +'</label>';       
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(node);
    }
}
```